# Alternative to @Test(expected=ExceptionClass.class) for testing exceptions in testng

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, testng

In TestNG, when we want to test a scenario in which an exception should be thrown one can write something like the following

```
@Test(expected=IndexOutOfBoundsException.class, expectedExceptionsMessageRegExp="*")
public void sampleExpectedExceptionTest() {
    List emptyList = new ArrayList();
    // Following line should throw an IndexOutOfBoundsException
    emptyList.get(0);
}
```

I have seen that some people write the tests in following style.

```
@Test
public void sampleExpectedExceptionTest() {
  // several lines here..

  List emptyList = new ArrayList();
  try {
    emptyList.get(0);
    Assert.assertFail("Expected IndexOutOfBoundsException but wasn't thrown");
  } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
    // ignore
  }

  // ... more lines of code asserting exceptions similar to above try catch scenario
}
```

I dislike the above style primarily because it is very verbose and also because people using it usually write multiple tests in one test case. However, the argument given in it's favour is that it allows users to pinpoint the assertion to a particular line and hence it is better.

Recently I learnt about JUnit's @Rule annotation

```
public class SampleExceptionTest {
   @Rule
   public final ExpectedException exception = ExpectedException.none();

   @Test
   public void sampleExpectedExceptionTest() {
       List emptyList = new ArrayList();

       exception.expect(IndexOutOfBoundsException.class);
       emptyList.get(0);
   }
}
```

This not only allows users to pinpoint the assertion to a line but it also discourages users to write multiple tests in one test case as once an exception is thrown the code exits and you can not test for multiple assertions. I want to know is there a similar option (or an idiom) in TestNG? I know that I can use expected

Comment: I would expect the exception to be thrown on the last line of the test method so I see little practical use to what you suggest...

Comment: Having more than one assertion in the test is usually a bad idea. If all of them fail, you will only know about the first assertion. You should have multiple tests instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you have a look at the [Catch-Exception](https://github.com/Codearte/catch-exception) library. It allows you to perform multiple assertions on the exception and any other relevant assertions. You can use it with JUnit and TestNG and any assertion framework you want.

Sample:

```
@Test
public void catchExceptionTest() {
    // given: an empty list
    List<Object> myList = new ArrayList<>();

    // when: we try to get the first element of the list
    // then: catch the exception if any is thrown
    catchException(myList).get(1);

    // then: we expect an IndexOutOfBoundsException
    Exception e = caughtException();
    // Use JUnit, TestNG, AssertJ etc. assertions on the "e" exception
    assert e instanceof IndexOutOfBoundsException;
}
```

You'll find more examples on the project page.

Comment: This is very useful. I also liked the concise version `verifyException(myList, IndexOutOfBoundsException.class).get(1);`  Although I am still surprised that testng developers have not considered this use case and made any provisions for this in the framework itself. I will wait for couple of days for other answers and if I don't get a better reply I will accept this answer.